# What is the difference between with, compact and array in when return view in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm little bit confuse
I want to know the difference between those three returns:

`return view('post', ['post' => $post]);`

`return view('post', compact('post'));`

`return view('post')->with('post'=>$post);`

So, can someone explain for me the difference in easy way.

Comment: First two are equivalent, see [`compact`'s doc](https://www.php.net/compact). Third one is invalid PHP. You probably meant `view('post')->with('post', $post)`. [The manual mentions it.](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#passing-data-to-views), seems like just another syntax to pass individual data (not in array form).

Comment: I just given an answer.  Hope you clear now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Array** : You may pass an array of data to views, like this :

```
return view('post', ['post' => $post]);
```

When passing information in this manner, the data should be an array with key / value pairs. Inside your view, you can then access each value using its corresponding key, such as `<?php echo $key; ?>`

---

**with()** : As an alternative to passing a complete **array** of data to the **[view](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-view)** helper function, you may use the **with** method to add individual pieces of data to the view :

```
return view('post')->with('post' => $post);
// multiple with method
return view('post')->with('post' => $post)->with('comment' => $comment);
```

---

**compact()** : Instead of using this type of passing data, you can use `compact()` to passing data. **[compact()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php)** is a built in **php function** that allows you create an **array** with variable names and their values. variable names must be pass to compact function as string argument and then, you with receive an **array**,  so compact passing the varibale on your view like the first method :

```
return view('post', compact('post'));
// same as
return view('post', ['post' => $post]);
```

See the official documentation of [Passing Data To Views](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#passing-data-to-views)

Answer (score 0):

```php
return view('post', ['post' => $post]);
return view('post', compact('post'));
```

these two are same as `view()` second argument can be `null or array`, [compact](https://www.php.net/compact) is a php function which take variable and generate associative array based on variable

and

```php
return view('post')->with('post'=>$post);
```

in this code `view()` laravel helper don't have second argument so yo can use [with()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#passing-data-to-views) function as chaining method and send data to view