# Laravel 7 - How does the return view()->with('some data) works exactly?

Tags: laravel

I have a code in Controller as

```
$messages['msg']  =  DB::table('contactus')->where('email',Auth::user()->email)->get();
   return view('contactmessages')->with($messages);
```

and in the blade

```
 @foreach($msg as $key => $message)
      <tr>
                  <th>{{$message->id}}</th>
                  <th>{{$message->message}}</th>
                  <th>{{$message->asked_on}}</th>
                  <th>{{$message->answered_on}}</th>
                  <th>{{$message->status}}</th>
              </tr>

            @endforeach
```

So, basically, I am sending an array of data, which are accessed by its key (in this case, it's `msg`),which has been converted into a variable. Is that correct?

Comment: basically sounds right

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64220632/what-is-the-difference-between-with-compact-and-array-in-when-return-view-in-la/64220964#64220964 check this

Comment: hope [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64221914/4575350) may helps

Comment: @sta I copied your answer, as is, for my reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered copied from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64221914/4575350) for my own reference

**Array** : You may pass an array of data to views, like this :

`return view('post', ['post' => $post]);`
When passing information in this manner, the data should be an array with key / value pairs. Inside your view, you can then access each value using its corresponding key, such as `<?php echo $key; ?>`

**with()** : As an alternative to passing a complete array of data to the view helper function, you may use the with method to add individual pieces of data to the view :

```
return view('post')->with('post' => $post);
// multiple with method
return view('post')->with('post' => $post)->with('comment' => $comment);
```

**compact()** : Instead of using this type of passing data, you can use compact() to passing data. compact() is a built in php function that allows you create an array with variable names and their values. variable names must be pass to compact function as string argument and then, you with receive an array, so compact passing the varibale on your view like the first method :

```
return view('post', compact('post'));
// same as
return view('post', ['post' => $post]);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use compact() instead of with() :

```
$messages  =  DB::table('contactus')->where('email',Auth::user()->email)->get();

return view('contactmessages', compact('messages'));
```

And blade could be

```
@foreach($messages as $item)
  <tr>
              <th>{{$item->id}}</th>
              <th>{{$item->message}}</th>
              <th>{{$item->asked_on}}</th>
              <th>{{$item->answered_on}}</th>
              <th>{{$item->status}}</th>
  </tr>

@endforeach
```