# cannot pass multiple variables to view laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a problem : I'm currently working on aproject of a web app for a library (it's for school).

And I want to return my view with 3 variables form queries, but it doesn't seem to work. It works for the 2 first but not for the 3rd.

here is my code :

```
$search_text = $_GET['query'];
            $results = DB::table('clients')->where('id','=',$search_text)->paginate(3); 
            $resultsloan = DB::table('emprunts')->where('clientid', '=', $search_text)->paginate(3);

            // compte le nombre de prets au client, si le nombre est supérieur à 4, le btn pour selectionner le client disparait et un msg d'avertissement apparait (dans formloan)
           $limitemprunts = Emprunt::WhereIn('clientid',[$search_text])->where('clientid',$search_text)->distinct()->get()->count();
            
            return view('crud.formloan', ['results'=>$results],['limitemprunts'=>$limitemprunts],['resultsloan'=>$resultsloan]);
```

But the $resultsloan seems to never get to my view ...
can someone please help me ?

Comment: Pass as _one_ array, not three

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between with, compact and array in when return view in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64220632/what-is-the-difference-between-with-compact-and-array-in-when-return-view-in-la)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing it wrong to view. You've to use it something like this:

`return view('foo',compact('key'=>'bazz','key'=>'bar','key'=>'foo bar'));`

or you can do it something like this:

`return view('foo',['key'=>'bazz', 'key'=>'bar', 'key'=>'foo bar']);`

Comment: thanks ! I changed it to 
return view('crud.formloan', ['results'=>$results,'limitemprunts'=>$limitemprunts,'resultsloan'=>$resultsloan]);

and now it works ! Ill have to wait for a few minutes before accepting your answer tho

Answer (score 0):

To expand on @Hasssaans's anwer, there are a few ways to pass variable to a view. This can depend on your coding style and also the amount you want to pass.

Another example I use:

```
return view('foo')->with(['key' => $value, 'users' => $users]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your return view as:

```
return view('crud.formloan', compact('results', 'limitemprunts', 'resultsloan'));
```