# How can i pass variables with using laravel mail template

Tags: laravel

```
    $slot=[
        'name'=>$r->name,
        'surname'=>$r->surname,
        'phone'=>$r->phone,
        'email'=>$r->email,
        'company_name'=>$r->company_name,
        'msg'=>$r->msg,
    ];
   
    return view('frontend.email.new')->with('name','surname','phone','email','company_name','msg');
```

How can i send $slot array to view.Tried so many things but couldnt pass anything help me please .

Comment: `->with('slot', $slot)`

Comment: You can use compact method as `return view('frontend.email.new', compact('slot'))`

Comment: Or `->with(['slot' => $slot])`; lots of approaches to sending data to a view

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between with, compact and array in when return view in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64220632/what-is-the-difference-between-with-compact-and-array-in-when-return-view-in-la)

Comment: After doin ->with('slot', $slot) i get this error No hint path defined for [mail]. (View: /Users/suleymanmutlu/Documents/GitHub/egeria/resources/views/frontend/email/new.blade.php)

Comment: @SemiusBlack that means passing the variable works, but in you use a view with `mail::` somewhere